# Least cost path barrier (R) (gdistance)

Tags: r, gis, r-raster

I'm trying to create a barrier (rivers) that can't be crossed by the least cost path.

I've created a transition layer using "areas" which contains the transition values on land, and on rivers. However, the barrier has a 'buffer' around it, with increasing values, instead of being a discrete barrier.

Cost raster and transition layer
[image: cost raster]
[image: Transition layer]
As can be seen, there's a 'buffer' around the barrier in the transition layer.

Any ideas on how to create a discrete boundary? preferably with the barrier as a value 1000, with everywhere else a value of 1.

Thanks!

code:
`library(gdistance)
    ## Create cost surface where "land" exists in the middle
    cost <- raster(nrow=100, ncol=100, 
               xmn=0, xmx=100, ymn=0, ymx=100, crs="+proj=utm")
    cost[] <- 10
    cost[cellFromRowColCombine(cost, 50:55,20:80)] <- 1000
    costf <- asFactor(cost < 100)
    ## Produce transition matrices, and correct because 8 directions
    trCost <- transition(costf, "areas", directions=16)
    trCost1 <- geoCorrection(trCost[[2]], type="c")
    plot(cost)
    plot(raster(trCost[[1]]))`

Comment: I answered this question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244364/least-cost-path-barrier-r-gdistance/244447#244447

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you define your real barrier as `NA` values and not with a high value, for which a probability is always possible:

```
library(gdistance)

## Create cost surface where "land" exists in the middle
cost <- raster(nrow=100, ncol=100, 
               xmn=0, xmx=100, ymn=0, ymx=100, crs="+proj=utm")
cost[] <- 10
cost[cellFromRowColCombine(cost, 50:55,20:80)] <- NA
costf <- asFactor(cost < 100)
## Produce transition matrices, and correct because 8 directions
trCost <- transition(costf, "areas", directions=16)
plot(cost)
plot(raster(trCost))
```